# How to display a 4 digit passcode/PIN when connecting to a Bluetooth Low Energy device?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a [tag:Bluetooth Low Energy] Bluetooth Low Energy device and when connecting to this device using an App from Google Play Store it displays a 4 numeric digit [passcode](/questions/tagged/passcode) passcode ( or [pin](/questions/tagged/pin) PIN) on the device and the App has a dialog to enter the passcode.

I am writing an app with [tag:Android 13.0] Android 13.0 to connect to the same Bluetooth Low Energy device.

- I can scan and discover the device
- I can connect using mDevice.connectGatt()
- I don't believe I have to use mDevice.createBond() as the actual bond state is BOND_BONDING and previous bond state is BOND_NONE in "mContext.registerReceiver(bondStateReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED));"
- I do get a "mContext.registerReceiver(pairingRequestBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST));" with a value of PAIRING_VARIANT_CONSENT

If I try to [pair](/questions/tagged/pair) pair the Bluetooth Low Energy device directly on my phone I don't see a passcode on the device, Android does not request the passcode and the device freezes with "Bt pair".

When I try to connect with my app, the device freezes at the exact same screen with the exact same text "Bt pair".

I have done research online including [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/) but with no luck.

**How do I instruct the device to show the passcode/pin to capture in my app?**

Any help will be appreciated!

Than you

```
 try {
    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    // No PIN is displayed and PIN is set to 0
    int pin = intent.getIntExtra("android.bluetooth.device.extra.PAIRING_KEY", 0);
    byte[] pinBytes;
    pinBytes = (""+pin).getBytes("UTF-8");
    // result is true
    boolean result = device.setPin(pinBytes); // TRUE
    // setPairingConfirmation() cannot be used as it is reserved for system app
    //device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When you say you paired the device directly from your phone, do you mean you used the Bluetooth Settings screen?

Comment: What kind of app did you use the first time? Was it an app specific for this BLE device?

Comment: Using my Pixel 4a, Settings, Connected devices, + Pair new device. It is a 3rd party app that can connect to 3 or 4 similar devices.

Comment: I was just wondering, because the Bluetooth Pairing uses a 6 digit number. Maybe this is something specific to this manufacturer? Can you try connecting to the device using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to see if this works as expected?

Comment: I have been reading posts about Bluetooth for a while now and I have never heard of that application. When I click connect the nRF Connect says CONNECTED BONDING.... The remote device says "Bt pair" as mentioned in my original question. The app displays the waiting cursor for about 20 seconds and then it says DISCONNECTED NOT BONDED. The app never asked for a PIN and the device never showed a PIN either. I use the word PIN but it could be a PassCode. I disconnected the device from my phone and reconnected twice with the 3rd party app. Both times it asked for a different 4 digits PIN number.

Comment: I can only assume that your device does not use a standard way of connecting... By the way, BLE requires an app to read and write, no need to connect via your smartphones settings. Most BLE devices do not even appear in the settings window

Comment: I just ask the manufacturer of the device to send me their exposed Bluetooth protocol. In the mean time, it is not the first time I see an app requesting to enter a PIN or passcode. Eventhough it is often 0000 like my Dodge does. Is there a BLE command that triggers a Bluetooth device to show a PIN/passcode?

Comment: This happens whenever you pair a device. Pairing happens automatically when requesting access to an encrypted characteristic. The actual pairing method (e.g. Just Works, Passcode, etc) depends on the devices capabilities